# History in calculator (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have code for running the history in the application.

My app screenshot:

[image: img]

How can I improve it so that the numbers are displayed immediately when pressed (as shown in the video), and not just by pressing `=`.

[image: gif]

```
// Connected to button "="
@IBAction func equalitySignPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if stillTyping {
        secondOperand = currentInput
    }
    dotIsPlaced = false

    addHistory(text: operationSign + displayResultLabel.text!)

    switch operationSign {
    case "+":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 + $1}
    case "-":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 - $1}
    case "×":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 * $1}
    case "÷":
        operateWithTwoOperands{$0 / $1}
    default: break
    }
}
func addHistory(text: String){
    //Add text
    resultLabelText.text =  resultLabelText.text! + "" + text
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to define a separate variable for the label string that is constantly updated using calls to `addHistory()` after every UIButton press (number or operator), and then the updating of the label itself handled by didSet inside the variable definition:

```
var resultLabelString: String = "" {
      didSet {
          self.resultLabelText.text = self.resultLabelText.text! + "" + resultLabelString
      }
}

func addHistory(text: String){
    self.resultLabelString =  text
}
```